# How to run ionic app built online on my system

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic application development, while searching through the net I saw a link which directed me to the **ionic creator**. Reading through it I was able to create an app.

After creating it, I downloaded the source files but now I am trying to run it on my computer. On the cmd screen, I typed `ionic serve`but I receive this error message `[ERROR] Sorry! ionic serve can only be run in an Ionic project directory`. Could someone please take me through the process of running the app on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run that command from project directory.

For example, if your application is in *C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\MyApp* you need to go to MyApp directory and there you can run `ionic serve` command.

Comment: [ERROR] Sorry! ionic serve can only be run in an Ionic project directory. is the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Ionic v1**

Install the latest version of the local Ionic CLI installed by typing the command:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

To start a new Ionic project, type the command:

```
ionic start myapp --type ionic1
```

Now go into the newly created myapp directory, and you will see directory called www inside.

Delete everything inside of the www folder, and move the unzipped files and folders from STEP 1 into the www folder. The directory structure should look like:

[image]

Next, move the directory called SCSS-MOVEME up one directory, and rename it to scss. This directory should now sit side-by-side with the www directory.

Now, run the command npm install from directly inside the myapp folder. This will install gulp.js and a few handy tasks, such as gulp-sass and gulp-minify-css.

Finally, in the ionic.config.json file, add the JavaScript property "gulpStartupTasks": ["sass", "watch"].

2. **Ionic v3.x**

This step requires you to have the latest version of the local Ionic CLI installed.

To start a new Ionic project, type the command:

```
ionic start myapp
```

Now go into the newly created myapp directory, and you will see directory called src inside.

Copy and paste the contents from your zip export into the src directory. You will want to overwrite the app directory, pages directory, and index.html

Source: [ZIP Export an Ionic Project](https://docs.usecreator.com/docs/zip-export-an-ionic-project)